# How to scrape multiple href values?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> Hello, I want to pull the links from this page. All the knowledge in that field comes in according to my own methods. But I just need the links. How can I scrape links?(Pyhton-Beautifulsoup)

```
make_list = base_soup.findAll('div', {'a class': 'link--muted no--text--decoration result-item'})
one_make = make_list.findAll('href')
print(one_make)
```

> The structure to extract the data is as follows:

```
<div class="cBox-body cBox-body--eyeCatcher" data-testid="no-top"> == $0
<a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" href="https://link structure"
```

> Every single link I want to collect is here.(link structure)

> I tried methods like.Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: i think this will help you, iterate make_list and get x.attrs["href"]

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

Iterate your `ResultSet` and extract the value of `href` attribute:

```
make_list = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'link--muted no--text--decoration result-item'})
    for e in make_list:
        print(e.get('href'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="cBox-body cBox-body--eyeCatcher" data-testid="no-top">
    <a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" href="https://link structure"></a>
</div>
<div class="cBox-body cBox-body--eyeCatcher" data-testid="no-top">
    <a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" href="https://link structure"></a>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

make_list = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'link--muted no--text--decoration result-item'})
for e in make_list:
    print(e.get('href'))
```

Comment: This answer has been successfully helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of code on how you can achieve that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ''' 
<div class="cBox-body cBox-body--eyeCatcher" data-testid="no-top"> == $0
    <a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" href="https://link structure"></a>
</div>
<div class="cBox-body cBox-body--eyeCatcher" data-testid="no-top"> == $0
    <a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" href="https://link example.2"></a>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
anchors = soup.find_all('a')

for anchor in anchors:
    print(anchor['href'])
```